# Why group name mentioned in testng.xml has high preference?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng

I have below `testng.xml` file where I've mentioned a group name to execute all testcases which has the same group name in my test suite

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestDive" verbose="0" parallel="methods" thread-count="2">

    <test name="HereWeGo" enabled="true">

        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="SANITY_PROD"/>
            </run>
        </groups>

        <classes>
            <class name="com.xyz.Classname"/>
        </classes>

    </test>
</suite>
```

Now if i pass the group name from command line e.g. `mvn clean test -DtestSuiteFile="config/sanity_suite.xml" -DincludeGroups=SANITY_STAGE`

The problem is it still executes the all test case with group `SANITY_PROD` as mentioned in xml file.

Am i doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about `includeGroups` attribute but try like this:

```
mvn clean test -Dgroups=SANITY_STAGE
```